# How to make ion-slides images all the same height?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I try to make a square component slideshow in ionic 3 but there are 2 images that are bigger than the rest. How can I make them all the same height?

```
<ion-slides *ngIf="ads && ads.length" autoplay="500" loop="true" speed="300">
  <ion-slide   *ngFor="let ad of ads">
    <img src="{{ad.img}}" />
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

[This is the "normal size"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDg0U.png)

[this one is too big and i need to make it smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjgte.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class for your img tag and set the pixels of the height as you want and also add `object—fit: cover` for the image not break

Comment: Are you sure? Because if you put for example: `img { height: 250px !important}` The image has to take that height. Maybe you have some class overriding the img element check out that.Also inspect the classes of ion-slide and ion-slides maybe is some height set it.

Comment: ok that works, but now the longer images have white space next to them. Something is wrong with the object fit

Comment: The object fit preserves the width and height that you set in the image, its only resizes to fit the container. Try to put the width like the height and play with that values as you wish .For example Try width 100% !important on the image and its parents.